# GetWindowText em C#

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, windows, api

como posso utilizar a função GetWindowText no c# ?
Preciso para converter esta função em delphi para c#

```
function FindWindowExt(partialTitle: string): HWND;
var
  hWndTemp: hWnd;
  iLenText: Integer;
  cTitletemp: array [0..254] of Char;
  sTitleTemp: string;
begin
  hWndTemp := FindWindow(nil, nil);
  while hWndTemp <> 0 do begin
    iLenText := GetWindowText(hWndTemp, cTitletemp, 255);
    sTitleTemp := cTitletemp;
    sTitleTemp := UpperCase(copy( sTitleTemp, 1, iLenText));
    partialTitle := UpperCase(partialTitle);
    if pos( partialTitle, sTitleTemp ) <> 0 then
      Break;
    hWndTemp := GetWindow(hWndTemp, GW_HWNDNEXT);
  end;
  result := hWndTemp;
end;
```

Comment: O jeito mais fácil seria fazer isso uma dll em C#, e importar essa dll no delphi, - [Referencia em Polonês](http://4programmers.net/Delphi/NET/PInvoke) :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o attributo `DllImport` para importar a função em uma classe:

```
public class WindowsUtils{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);
}
```

Depois é só usar como uma função estática qualquer.